# Login to web page and export table to CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I am trying to login to web page and export table to CSV file. There is a login form on `https://website.com/login` and table on `https://website.com/table`. Current code does not give any error but it is not able to scrape correct table. What can possibly be wrong?

Current code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

payload = {'MyUsername': 'username', 'MyPassword': 'password'}
url = 'https://website.com/login'
html = requests.get(url, data=payload).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[-1]
print(df)
df.to_csv('my data.csv')
```

Here is source code of web page with table:

[image]

Table structure is the same for each row. Columns are like slick-cell 10 r0, slick-cell 10 r1 etc.

Basically I am trying to get it working on python. This one works for login and redirection to table page but not able to export data from table:

C#:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Table_Scrape
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://website.com/login");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys("MYusername");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("MYpassword");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnSubmit_6")).Click();

            driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnContinue")).Click();

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://website.com/table");

            IList<IWebElement> allElement = driver.FindElements(By.Xapth("//div[contains(@class,'slick-cell')]"));
            foreach (IWebElement element in allElement)
            {
                string cellText = element.Text;
                Console.WriteLine(cellText);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Selenium` or `bs4` isnt an option? Works for my codes, but would adda little weight

Comment: Yes, also possible. At the moment I am just searching for working solution to get an idea.

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to do a GET from the /table page, or is that an automatic redirection after successful login? Anyway, your login is most likely not working. Trace a successful browser login and read of the /table using e.g. Telerik Fiddler then reproduce the headers/content in your Python code.

Comment: I think so too, that my login is not working correct

Comment: login most usually (IME) uses GET then POST, but Fiddler will tell you exactly what your site needs..

Comment: @hatman is it possible to share the url?